# In R, why does subsetting a negative numeric value of length 1 result in widely different results depending on what you subset it on?

Tags: r

In R, I saw that if we subset a negative number by negative values, we get -1. If somehow a 1 is placed in, we get numeric(0), and if positive numbers are the indices, we get NA's. Why is this?

```
> V <- -1
> V[-c(3,4)]
  [1] -1
> V[-c(1,3,4)]
  numeric(0)
> V[c(1,3,4)]
  [1] -1 NA NA
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with negative numbers. You'll get same results for `V <- 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second an  third case, the actual index was present, and it results in removing that element to results in numeric(0) for the second case and in third with positive index, third and fourth doesn't exist and gives NA

```
c(1, 4, 3)[c(5, 6)] # // it is vector of length 3, so 5th and 6th doesn't exist
#[1] NA NA

c(1, 4, 3)[-c(5, 6)] # // no values in 5th and 6th to remove
#[1] 1 4 3    # // so it returns the original vector
```

---

In the OP's case

```
V[-1] # // returns numeric(0) as the first and only element is removed
#numeric(0)
```